# tSqoopImport component of Talend Open Studio for BigData(5.6.2) throws error when connecting to MySQL database on MapR cluster

Tags: mysql, talend, mapr, bigdata

1. Use case: Need to connect Talend's bigdata component i.e.
   tSqoopImport to MySQL DB residing on MapR cluster.

   > Talend Open studio for Big-data(5.6.2) resides on my workstation.
   >   MySQL (5.5) database installed on 5 node MapR (M3-edition) cluster.
   >   Cluster is physical setup and accessible via remote clients like putty & MobaX

   --> Have attached the snapshot of the talend job representing my use case. Initially am trying to establish the connection from Sqoop
   component on Talend to MySQL Database on MapR cluster to extract
   data from database tables.

[image]

Below is the complete log of talend job console after below changes were made as specified by tobi6 (StackOF user).

1) SSH is working fine (checked).
2) Port 3306 is not blocked. (same can be accessed via java program running on eclipse).
3) MySQL server is running fine.
4) Fired SQL queries from remote as well as local machine (works fine).
5) Restarted MySQL and its services.

```
Starting job X_TSqoopImportClusterTest at 11:15 30/05/2017.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3548
[statistics] connected
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
[WARN ]: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[WARN ]: org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager - Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool - Beginning code generation
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `Persons` AS t LIMIT 1
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `Persons` AS t LIMIT 1
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager - $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is not set
Note: \tmp\sqoop-Mohan.Jay\compile\a091fbc8c79e3335a228dd95aabe8dbc\Persons.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager - Writing jar file: \tmp\sqoop-Mohan.Jay\compile\a091fbc8c79e3335a228dd95aabe8dbc\Persons.jar
[WARN ]: org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager - It looks like you are importing from mysql.
[WARN ]: org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager - This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
[WARN ]: org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager - option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager - Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase - Beginning import of Persons
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
[INFO ]: org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase - Setting default value for hadoop.job.history.user.location=none
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
[WARN ]: org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase - SQOOP_HOME is unset. May not be able to find all job dependencies.
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /172.25.1.26:8032
Some error on socket 1092
Some error on socket 1112
Some error on socket 1124
2017-05-30 11:15:26,0625 ERROR Cidcache fs/client/fileclient/cc/cidcache.cc:1288 Thread: 6612 Lookup of volume users failed, error Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown(108), CLDB: 172.25.1.27:7222 backing off ...
Some error on socket 1124
2017-05-30 11:15:28,0737 ERROR Cidcache fs/client/fileclient/cc/cidcache.cc:1288 Thread: 6612 Lookup of volume users failed, error Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown(108), CLDB: 172.25.1.28:7222 backing off ...
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:1
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_1495790825330_0005
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.security.ExternalTokenManagerFactory - Initialized external token manager class - com.mapr.hadoop.yarn.security.MapRTicketManager
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl - Submitted application application_1495790825330_0005
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://terminal1:8088/proxy/application_1495790825330_0005/
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - Running job: job_1495790825330_0005
```

Comment: Have update the latest error stack which shows up on talend job console.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectException usually means that the server you are trying to reach is not accessible on that port.

If SSH is working fine then somewhere in the path from the Talend job to the MySQL server access to the port 3306 is blocked - or the port is a different one.

Comment: Have pasted the latest error from talend job console  which occurred after below changes were made as specified you suggested. @tobi6
</br>

**1) SSH is working fine (checked).
2) Port 3306 is not blocked. (same can be accessed via java program running on eclipse). 
3) MySQL server is running fine. 
4) Fired SQL queries from remote as well as local machine (works fine). 
5) Restarted MySQL and its services.**